# Assigning string value to DataGridViewTextBoxColumn gives Int32 error

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Trying to assign a string "$57,834" to a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` `Amt`:

```vb
For Each dgr As DataGridViewRow In dgvExpSubject.Rows
    dgr.Cells("Amt").Value = Format(amt, AG.MASK_DOLLARS)
```

Gives this error:

> DataGridView Exception: $57,834 is not a valid value for Int32

The `Amt` column is not Int32, it is `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`. Should be able to assign a string value.

Comment: DataGridViewTextBoxColumn tells you that for inputting your data you will receive a "textbox" control (as opposed to a "checkbox" or something else). What is the type of the data stored in that column is a completely separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column may contain `TextBoxes` but the underlying data type is `Integer`, so the values you assign in the cells have to be `Integer` values. If you want those values displayed as currency then let the grid do the formatting. Set the `DefaultCellStyle.Format` property of the column to your format string, i.e. `AG.MASK_DOLLARS`, and then simply assign `amt` to the `Value` of the cell.

BTW, if you are going to format a single value, don't use `Format`. We're not writing VB6 code. Call the `ToString` method of the value itself. That means that, if you were going to do it the way you're trying to, you do this:

```vb
dgr.Cells("Amt").Value = amt.ToString(AG.MASK_DOLLARS)
```

Comment: Thanks. And, yes, I'm coming from VB6 after a ~20 year hiatus in Unix/dBase. Got a lot to catch up.